# Is there any way to use Alias in Salesforce Report

Tags: reporting, analytics

I have a report on a custom Report Type on say two objects Account and Multichannel Consent. Now in the Report there are some fields like Multichannel Consent : Record type, but that needs to appear as say 'Channel', Is there any way to use some alias of this field, one way around we found is to use formula field with label exact matching the values.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the Report Type, click on the field you want to change, then click Edit Properties and you can change the "Display As" property, which will change the column header

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot paul, i'm trying to implement it and will let you know